# CSS variables are not statically checked

Tags: css

For a course on webtech we need to write a static webpage. This webpage must be compliant with the jigsaw w3c css validator. We are stuck on working out the last warning:

> Due to their dynamic nature, CSS variables are currently not statically checked

The code that causes it is:

```
.gallery {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 5vw;
  margin-left: 5vw;
  width: 50vw;
  margin-bottom: 1vw;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--num-cols), 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  gap: 0.5vw;
}
```

Specifically, the line "grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--num-cols), 1fr);". Currently the variable `--num-cols` is used to specify how many columns a specific gallery must have.

Is there a way to make it compliant with the validator, while still keeping functionality as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a default value in case the variable isn't defined and you're set:

```css
.gallery {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--num-cols, 1), 1fr);
}
```